# Repeat some images inside folder

Tags: python, save, repeat, opencv

I have a dataset folder consists of sub-folders, each of the sub-folders must contain 8 images, but some of them contain less than 8, such as for example 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or maybe 8. I want to equalize all of them into 8 images each by repeating the existing images beginning from the first one available to the last one until 8 images is reached, then stop and save all of them in the same directory path.

I made loop to reach images and read them as code below, but I'm faced with the problem of how can I repeat them until 8 images is reached for each folder.

```
ID_Paths = "path\of\dataset\folder"
listing = os.listdir(ID_Paths)
for fold_Path in listing:
    print("NOW input images of new individual... ", fold_Path)
    image_fold = os.listdir(ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path)
    for file in image_fold:
        segments = os.listdir(ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path + "\\" + file)
        im = ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path + "\\" + file + "\\" + segments
        test_image = cv2.imread(im)
```

Comment: To repeat the image file within a sub-folder, the copies will need to be given different unique names. How do you proposed to do that?

Comment: @martineau thank you for your reply. yes exactly, I want to resave the images in the same folder, so the proposed name may be "image_name9", "image_name10", etc. Because the original images is from "image_name1" to "image_name8". Have you any idea how can I do that ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's still a number of things unspecified in your answer, but in the interests of providing you with something that's hopefully will at least be close to what you want, I'll post an answer. It uses a couple of functions from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module to generate filenames for the copied files. It just copies the image files using the [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) function instead of using the `cv2` module to do to read each one into memory and then write it out again—something which just doesn't seem necessary since you're not doing anything else to the images.

I've tried to make the variable names very understandable and added comments at crucial places.

```
from itertools import count, cycle
import os
import os.path
from shutil import copyfile

ID_Paths = r"path\of\dataset\folder"
REQ_NUM_IMGS = 8  # Required number of image files in each subfolder.

# Subfolders in ID_Paths.
subfolders = [subfolder for subfolder in os.listdir(ID_Paths)
                  if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(ID_Paths, subfolder))]

# Equalize number of (image) files in each subfolder.
for subfolder in subfolders:
    print("NOW input images of new individual...", subfolder)

    # Assumes all files in subfolder are image files.
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(ID_Paths, subfolder)
    image_filenames = os.listdir(subfolder_path)
    print(' original files:', image_filenames)

    shortage = REQ_NUM_IMGS - len(image_filenames)
    if shortage > 0:  # Need repeats?
        for i, src_img_filename in zip(count(REQ_NUM_IMGS+1),
                                       cycle(image_filenames)):
            src_imgfile_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, src_img_filename)
            img_filename, img_ext = os.path.splitext(src_img_filename)
            suffix = '_' + str(i)
            dst_img_filename = os.path.join(subfolder_path,
                                            img_filename+suffix+img_ext)
            dst_imgfile_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, dst_img_filename)
            print('   copying: {}\n'
                  '        to: {}'.format(src_imgfile_path, dst_imgfile_path))
            copyfile(src_imgfile_path, dst_imgfile_path)
            shortage -= 1
            if shortage == 0:
                break
```